# How to get CustomerID from StripeEvents if ChargeSucceeded in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments

I want CustomerID from StripeEvents.I have json retrieve from strip webhook. I have already done some code but since customerID get

> NULL

```
               var bodyStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
                bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var json = bodyStream.ReadToEnd();

                var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ParseEvent(json);

                // Handle the event
                if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.ChargeSucceeded)
                {
                    var CustomerID = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Customer;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

For ChargeSucceeded you'll get a Charge object back, not a Customer, so I would do something like this instead:

```
if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.ChargeSucceeded)
{
    var charge = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Charge;
    var CustomerID = charge.CustomerId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get it:

```
Event stripeEvent = EventUtility.ParseEvent(body, false);
dynamic obj = stripeEvent.Data.Object;
string cust = obj.CustomerId;
```