# ASP.Net Core parse Stripe Webhook JSON Response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am working with Stripe/Stripe.net Webhooks in my ASP.Net Core app. I am trying to map an object where I can use the properties returned from the Webhook JSON response and save various properties into my database. Using Postman, I am able to receive the sample JSON that I got from Stripe test webhooks in my Controller method and parse the JSON using

```
var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
Event stripeEvent = EventUtility.ParseEvent(json);
```

which returns:

```
stripeEvent = {<Stripe.Event@2269235 id=evt_00000000000000> JSON: {"id": "evt_00000000000000", "object": "event", "account": null, "api_version": "2020-03-02", "created": 1326853478, "data": {    "object": { "id": "ch_00000000000000", "...
```

I am needing to map the JSON from the RawObject ChildrenTokens into a model but I'm not able to access the ChildrenTokens through C#. Is there any way to be able to map these properties?

Comment: Can you check this thread to see if it's helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831861/how-to-get-customerid-from-stripeevents-if-chargesucceeded-in-c-sharp   In the answer, stripeEvent.Data.Object is accessed and through it, CustomerId is accessed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick here is to cast the `stripeEvent.Data.Object` as the specific class that the underlying event data should represent. Typically, you'll have a switch or if statement checking the `stripeEvent.Type`.

For instance, if the type of the event is `payment_intent.succeeded`, then the underlying data would be a PaymentIntent and you might have the following code to check the type, then cast to that type.

```
if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.PaymentIntentSucceeded)
{
  var paymentIntent = stripeEvent.Data.Object as PaymentIntent;
}
```

From there, you can interact with the `paymentIntent` and it's related properties.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi bcedergren, I'm writing here not to post an answer. This has already been done. But I have a question. Perhaps you have the answer for me. Please have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874833/asp-net-core-3-1-getting-current-identity-user-within-stripe-httppostwebhook) I'm trying to access my database within the webhook POST, but `var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);` is returning NULL

Comment: Hi I can't find any documentation of every cast type like "PaymentIntent" but for Checkout or Session for example, where can we access to a description of all of these types ? Thanks you

Comment: Hey Alexy, all the Entity types you can cast into are available in the open source SDK: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/tree/master/src/Stripe.net/Entities